# Safely passing data from a Windows 8 application to a web service

Tags: web-services, encryption, windows-8, password-encryption

I am building a windows 8 application which will be used as the interface to a web service I have running.

I need to find a safe way of encrypting sensitive data to pass, then decrypt it the other end.

Two things I need to do (as they may require separate methods);

1) User will enter a username and password which needs to be authenticated

2) User will enter personal information to be saved.

Now I have looked at many encryption/decryption methods, but I cannot find anything which is common place between the two. For example System.Security.Cryptography is not available within the windows 8 app, and my website can't use CryptographicEngine.

I am basically trying to find the best way to DO what I need to do. Along with a way of actually doing it in code.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use the same namespaces, as you have recognized.  What you need to do is settle on a standard crypto algorithm on both ends.

Here is a discussion for one approach on the Win8 side using AES256.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/8f9ecac4-80d2-47c8-8c41-9d7877565bf5

Here is a solution for doing AES256 with regular .NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to secure the channel, then use an HTTPS web service, that's what HTTPS was designed for. The client-side HttpWebRequest class should just do the rest for you.

You'll need a certificate on the web server.